# DB2 Convert Each Column to a Row based on ID

Tags: sql, db2, pivot, db2-luw

Not sure where to start with this, I've read about pivot/lateral but don't fully understand their use cases so I'm not sure if they apply here. They don't appear to be in my version of DB2 regardless.

Example Starting Table

```
ID, Firstname, Lastname, Age
0, John, Smith, 30
1, Jane, Doe, 40
2, Fake, Name, 50
```

I'm looking to pivot this table to the following...

Example Expected Results

```
Id, ColumnName, ColumnValue
0, Firstname, John
0, Lastname, Smith
0, Age, 30
1, Firstname, Jane
1, LastName, Doe
1, Age, 40
2, FirstName, Fake
2, LastName, Name
2, Age, 50
```

How should I go about doing this? Is there a name for this action?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pivot syntax doesn't exist in DB2, you can use lateral like this:

```
with table1 (ID, Firstname, Lastname, Age) as (
  values
  (0, 'John', 'Smith', 30),
  (1, 'Jane', 'Doe', 40),
  (2, 'Fake', 'Name', 50)
)
select
  ID,rowtocolumns.*
from table1
  cross join lateral (
    values
    ('Firstname', Firstname),
    ('Lastname', Lastname),
    ('Age', varchar(age))
  ) as rowtocolumns(ColumnName, ColumnValue)
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much. I was using this before, http://www.dbatodba.com/db2/how-to-do/how-to-convert-columns-to-rows-and-rows-to-columns/ but couldn't understand it with the data provided. Using my example data really helped me understand. Appreciate it!